# Visual Basic - Extracting text from a webpage

Tags: html, vba, visual-studio-2013

My program is designed to search Amazon and extract bits of data from the results - such as product name and price.

So far, my program pastes what the user has typed into `txt_Search` and presses 'Go' on the page. Here is the code so far:

```
    Private Sub btn_Search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Search.Click
    Dim SearchTerm As String

    'Set SearchTerm as text input
    SearchTerm = txt_Search.Text

    'Identify the search text box
    Dim AmazonElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = web_Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Input")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In AmazonElementCollection
        Dim searchtextbox As String = curElement.GetAttribute("id").ToString
        If searchtextbox = "twotabsearchtextbox" Then
            'Populate the search text box
            curElement.SetAttribute("Value", searchterm)
        End If
    Next

    'BUTTON CLICK: Search button
    '<input type="submit" value="Go" class="nav-submit-input" title="Go">
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In AmazonElementCollection
        'Find the Go button
        If curElement.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Go") Then
            'Function to click the button
            curElement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

So this all works fine as it does all this on a web browser object called `web_Browser`. But how do I take the text off the web page for the first result for example and put it into a textbox. I would like the title of the first result to be put into a textbox called `txt_Title`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event handler for the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of your web_browser control.

In that event handler, you can use the same method to find your results element as you have done to find the search text box and the search button, that is:  loop through the elements of the document and use the properties of the elements to identify the one you want.

This might look something like this:

**Add event handler:**

```
    If curElement.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Go") Then
        'Add the handler
        AddHandler web_Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf myDocumentCompleted

        'Function to click the button
        curElement.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
```

**Event handler implementation:**

```
Private Sub myDocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim AmazonElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = web_Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("something you need to figure out")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In AmazonElementCollection
        Dim resultText As String = curElement.GetAttribute("id").ToString
        If resultText = "something you need to figure out" Then
            'Populate the text box
            txt_Title.Text = curElement.innerHTML;
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Note:**  I haven't run this through a compiler or tested it, so be prepared for some problems, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've been trying to work out how to use the handler and where to use it. So far I've defined the event in a module using this code: `Public Event DocumentCompleted As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler` and using `Dim web_URL = web_Browser.Url
        AddHandler web_Browser, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf web_URL)` after my program runs the code in my question. However it comes back with "'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses)". Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think it should be AddHandler web_Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf myDocumentCompletedMethod